# Offset modifier in Loki doesn't seem to work

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-loki

I am new with Loki and I am trying to write simple queryes. One of them is:

```
count_over_time({job="grafana"}[5m] offset 5m)
```

but I get an error:

```
parse error at line 1, col 37: syntax error: unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting )
```

Could anybody tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: It seems to be a bug.